# Cards 101 using VB

Tags: vb.net

Having a real difficult time with this. I have 2 stacks of cards.. user vs computer. The cards are dealt and properly displayed, that works just fine. Now the problem is how do I actually compare the 2 stacks of cards? So it the user gets say.. a "9" and the computer gets an "8", the user would get a point. There are 52 images loaded in with names like 'AceofClubs.png'. So, how can I give the respective image a value to compare? Thanks!

```
  Public Enum Suit
Diamonds
Spades
Clubs
Hearts
```

End Enum

Public Enum FaceValue
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13
    Ace = 14
End Enum

Public Class Card
    Private ReadOnly faceVal As FaceValue
    Private isCardUp As Boolean
    Private ReadOnly suit As Suit

```
Public ReadOnly Property FaceVal As FaceValue
    Get
        Return Me.faceVal
    End Get
End Property

Public Property IsCardUp As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me.isCardUp
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        Me.isCardUp = value
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Suit As Suit
    Get
        Return Me.suit
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal suit As Suit, ByVal faceVal As FaceValue, ByVal isCardUp As Boolean)
    MyBase.New()
    Me.suit = suit
    Me.faceVal = faceVal
    Me.isCardUp = isCardUp
End Sub

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String 
    Return String.Concat("The", Me.faceVal.ToString(), "of", Me.suit.ToString())
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Use an array of a Struct that has both image and value.

Comment: Show us your `Card` Class, it should be in there.

Comment: Exact duplicate under a different account.

Answer (score 4):

Embrace OOP.  Instead of creating a bunch of arrays, create an object to hold each one of your cards, e.g.

```
public class Card
{
   public Image Image {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

You can then utilize a `List` which you'll load through your algorithms, e.g.

```
 var myCards = new List<Card> {new Card{Image=...,Name="Ace", Value="12"}};
```

After you load all of your cards into the appropriate lists, you can simply compare properties of the object, e.g.

```
 if(computerCard.Value > myCard.Value) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited my main post.. but I am getting multiple errors using the code you wrote. Am I supposed to replace the 'get' and 'set'? If so, with what? I'm sorry but I'm very confused. The 'var'.. do I have to do that line of code for all 52 pictures to give each picture a value? I'm so lost.. please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a Card class as George shows, you would probably then create a Hand class to hold each player's hand.  The Hand class would have a List(Of Card) to hold the cards for the hand.  And you might even a Deck class to represent the deck of cards.

Download the VB Card Game starter kit and have a look at how it represents the cards, decks, and hands.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ba4638ad-a2d2-49e5-ae46-94e0f747cae0

EDIT:  The card game starter kit defines their card class similar to this:

```
Public Enum Suit
    Diamonds
    Spades
    Clubs
    Hearts
End Enum

Public Enum FaceValue
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13
    Ace = 14
End Enum

Public Class Card
    Private ReadOnly faceVal As FaceValue
    Private isCardUp As Boolean
    Private ReadOnly suit As Suit

    Public ReadOnly Property FaceVal As FaceValue
        Get
            Return Me.faceVal
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property IsCardUp As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.isCardUp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.isCardUp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Suit As Suit
        Get
            Return Me.suit
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal suit As Suit, ByVal faceVal As FaceValue, ByVal isCardUp As Boolean)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.suit = suit
        Me.faceVal = faceVal
        Me.isCardUp = isCardUp
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String 
        Return String.Concat("The", Me.faceVal.ToString(), "of", Me.suit.ToString())
    End Function
End Class
```

Then in the Deck class, they used List(Of Card) to hold the cards and initialized the deck in Sub New like this:

```
Public Sub New
    'cards is a List(Of Card) declared elsewhere

    For Each s As Suit in Enum.GetValues(GetType(Suit))
        For Each v As FaceValue in Enum.GetValues(GetType(FaceValue))
            cards.Add(New Card(s, v, true))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Look at the card game starter kit and specifically, look at the folder CardGameFramework for the definitions of the Card, Deck, and Hand classes.

Each Hand will also have a List(Of Card) to hold the cards in the hand.  So when the cards are dealt, the card is removed from the Deck and added to the Hand.  In the starter kit, the Deck class has a Draw method

Comment: How do I write the actual property procedure though? To give each card a numerical value?

Comment: @Joe - If you look at the card game starter kit, they use an Enum to define the face value of each card.  So a two has a value of 2, a three a value of three, etc.  A jack has a value of 11, queen: 12, king: 13, and Ace 14.  Of course you can adjust the Enum to suit your needs.

Comment: I get the Enum.. but how in the world does the program know what image is pulled up? I don't understand this at all. If an image of a ten comes up.. how does the program recognize this?

Comment: @Joe - The program wouldn't care about the image.  The image is only for display purposes.  The logic of the game would use the Card, Hand, and Deck classes.  For the game of war, for example, there would be two Card instances.  To see which one is higher, you would just compare the FaceValue properties.  The image of the card would only be used to display them on the screen.